TexLive install fails
I've tried this on Windows 11 several times over the last few days, including extracting the files first and then running install-tl-windows.bat as admin, but it always fails with the same error, checksum failures for texlive-scripts.doc.tar.xz and texlive-scripts.tar.xz.
Any suggestions would be welcome!

try with a different mirror

This usually happens, when a mirror is out of sync, e.g., while the TeX Live repository of a mirror is updated. It can also happen, if such an update has an error. Sometimes is happens, if the mirror is changed while the installation happen and the two (or more) mirrors provide different versions. Using a dedicated mirror instead of the generic ctan.org can help.

Another suggestion would be to use the ISO for the installation (and optionally try updating it later).

Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried several other mirrors with the same effect. MikTex is working so I'll stick with that for now and try to install it again another day.
